# CMake and lcov: gcno files not found

Tags: c++, cmake, code-coverage, gcov, lcov

I am trying to get code coverage on my CMake based project (which consists of several targets).

First I generate gcno files with:

```
lcov -b . -d . -o coverage.output --capture --initial
```

The **.gcno* are generated in

```
build_dir/[target_dir]/CMakeFiles/[target_dir].dir
```

Then I run my tests which generate **.gcna* files in

```
build_dir/tests/CMakeFiles/[target_dir].dir
```

When I now run lcov again:

```
lcov -b . -d . -o coverage.output --capture
```

I get the following error:

```
Scanning . for .gcda files ...
Found 23 data files in .
Processing Base.dir/DateTools.cpp.gcda
geninfo: ERROR: build_gcov/tests/CMakeFiles/Base.dir/DateTools.cpp.gcno: could not open file
```

When I manually move the **.gcno* file to the directory where the **.gcda* is generated it seems to work.

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have figured it out how to use lcov with CMake and bundled everything in a [cmake module](https://github.com/bilke/cmake-modules/blob/master/CodeCoverage.cmake).